# pattern match HTTpoison response Elixir

Tags: elixir, httpoison

Is there any way that we can pattern match the error response of `httpoison` ? I was doing this

```
case HTTPoison.get!(url, [], []) do
  %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason} ->
    IO.inspect "Media: #{reason}!"
    :timer.sleep(:timer.seconds(3))
    do_loop(starting, ending, interval, camera_exid)
  response ->
    upload(response.status_code, response.body, starting, camera_exid)
    do_loop(starting + interval, ending, interval, camera_exid)
end
```

But It didn't catch the `timeout` and gave me error as

```
** (HTTPoison.Error) :timeout
    (httpoison) lib/httpoison.ex:66: HTTPoison.request!/5
    (extractor) lib/snapshot/snap_extractor.ex:67: Extractor.SnapExtractor.do_loop/4
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:651: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:651: Enum.each/2
```

I think am doing it in wrong way.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HTTPoison.get!` will `raise` an exception, not return one, so you need to use `try ... rescue ...`:

```
try do
  response = HTTPoison.get!(url, [], [])
  upload(response.status_code, response.body, starting, camera_exid)
  do_loop(starting + interval, ending, interval, camera_exid)
rescue
  %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason} ->
    IO.inspect "Media: #{reason}!"
    :timer.sleep(:timer.seconds(3))
    do_loop(starting, ending, interval, camera_exid)
end
```

This is however not considered good code since HTTPoison also has `get` which returns `{:ok, response}` or `{:error, error}` which you can use as follows:

```
case HTTPoison.get(url, [], []) do
  {:ok, response} ->
    upload(response.status_code, response.body, starting, camera_exid)
    do_loop(starting + interval, ending, interval, camera_exid)
  {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
    IO.inspect "Media: #{reason}!"
    :timer.sleep(:timer.seconds(3))
    do_loop(starting, ending, interval, camera_exid)
end
```

Comment: I don't think the first part is valid syntax, at least in Elixir 1.7+. I get an `invalid "rescue" clause. The clause should match on an alias, a variable or be in the "var in [alias]" format` compile error for something similar whereas `e in SomeError ->` is fine.